# spring roo generate repositories for all entities

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I am using spring roo 1.2.5 with oracle database

My goal is to create the entities, repositories and service classes in seperate packages

I was able to generate all the entities using the single command :

```
database reverse engineer --schema schema_name --activeRecord false --disableGeneratedIdentifiers true --disableVersionFields true --package ~domain
```

but when I want to generate the repositories, I am forced to proceed one by one using the command :

```
repository jpa --interface MyInterface --entity MyEntity
```

Is there a way to generate all repositories in one command in the same way as the entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Repositories**

I don't believe there is an `all` option for generating `repository jpa`. You could generate a Roo script with an external tool. Scan for all entities (e.g. list files in your domain package) and generate a line for each entity

`repository jpa --interface ~.repo.${ENTITY}Repository --entity ~.domain.${ENTITY}`

replacing `${ENTITY}` with actual entity class name. Save the generated script as a file. Then run this script with

`script --file ...`

**Services**

For service interfaces and classes use

`service all`

Comment: thank you for your reply, do you have an example about how to generate the script with an external tool

Comment: Then what is different in generating one by one ?

Answer (score 1):

Completing the answer of @Luka Klepec:

According to the [Spring Roo Appendix A](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/command-index.html), you have to complete the command as follows

**Services**

To create the service interfaces and classes use:

**service all --interfacePackage ~.service --classPackage ~.service.impl**

The package **~.service** will contain interfaces and **~.service.impl** will contain the interfaces  implementarions